# What is the difference between Runtime Polymorphism and Dynamic Binding in Java?

Tags: java

Why there are three terms for one type of concept "Runtime polymorphism", "Dynamic method dispatch" and "Dynamic binding". Is Binding means only call to an overriden method or any kind of method? These things are really confusing.